# How to write content to a specific location in the file using FileWriter?

Tags: java, file-io

I am using Java `FileWriter` to write a content into the existing file, but the content is added to the end of the file.  I want to add the content at a specific location.  Can anyone help me in how to do this?

I am currently doing something like this:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileW,true);
fileWriter.append(metaData.toString());
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Is your aim to *insert* data in the middle of a file? If so, most file systems basically don't support this. You need to:

- Create a new file
- Copy the first part of your old file to the new file
- Write your new data to the new file
- Copy the rest of your old file to the new file
- Optionally delete/rename the old file and rename the new file so it now appears in the same place as the old file

Comment: If using `RandomAccessFile`, creating a new file wouldn't be required if you can allocate a buffer big enough to contain the file data which needs to be "shifted" ahead. But yes, I agree, automatic "shifting" is not supported.

Comment: @Sanjay: In that case, you're not really *inserting* data - you're *overwriting* a portion of the file, and so the rest of my answer after the first question doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

To write at a specific location guided by the file pointer, you'll have to use the [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class. But messing around with file pointers is a bit hairy so is there any reason why you'd want to write "text" using random access?

A bit more details would help.

Comment: I am generated html file using Apache Tika, Now I want to add metadata inside the head tag of the html file. Using FileWriter I am able to add the metadata at the end of the file. But the need is i want place metadata inside head tag.

Comment: In that case, the simplest solution would be write a new file "with" the modified meta data along with the originally generated HTML content. What you do is simply keep on "reading" lines from the source HTML and writing them to a new destination HTML. As soon as you encounter the string corresponding to the HEAD tag, add your metadata to the string, create a new string and write it to the target HTML file. But then again, I feel that you should first approach the Tika folks and see if there is a possibility of adding metadata directly to the generated file.

Comment: Tika is generating xhtml file with the metadata included. But the problem is when rtf document is converted into xhtml file through Tika, there were no html tags like bold,italic etc  were not present in the generated xhtml file. I need a rtf converted document to html format with all the html tags present. So, I am converting the rtf document to html using HtmlEditorKit, then trying to add the metadata into the generated html file. Hope Tika doesn't have the facility to add the metadata separately into the generated file